# Create a Pthread that runs to completion in background

Tags: c, multithreading, shell, pthreads

I am new to pthreads, and I am trying to create my own shell script in C that has a variety of simple inputs, some of which are fairly time consuming.  I would like to be able to create a pthread that continues to work on such tasks while I may continue to use the shell for other commands.

However, no matter what I try my shell always seems to wait until completion of the most recently created pthread before allowing me to input anything else.

I intend to do this solely with threads, not child processes, so fork() is not an option for me here.

Essentially, my question is how can I create a thread that runs completely independently, to completion, in the background of a shell script in order for me to continue using the shell without significant interruption.

Comment: context please? what is the part of your C program that is spawning the pthread? Be specific about what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You have to code the program that creates a pthread that does whatever you want to do. Lets assume you have that program .exe file and it's called 'myProgram'. If you want to make a script that provides input to myProgram while not "freezing" the shell

```
#!/bin/bash
./myProgram input_1 input_2 input_3 input_4&
./myProgram input_1 input_2 input_3 input_4;
```

The above script runs myProgram 2 times with 2 sets of command line arguments. The use of the symbol '&' at the end of the second line makes myProgram run in the background so you can keep on using the shell. If you want to run myProgram multiple times, simply add '&' at the end of each run command. Each program execution will run in the background and you will be able to keep on using the shell while the programs are still running.